# Conditional distribution of $Z$ given $Z=X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variables with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. If $Z=min(X,Y)$, find the conditional distribution of $Z$ given $Z=X$

My try:

I found the pdf of the random variable $Z$ using the fact that the CDF of $Z$ is:
$$F_{z}(z)=P(Z \leq z)=P(\min (X, Y) \leq z)=1-P(\min (X, Y)>z)$$
So we have:
$$F_Z(z)=1-P(X>z)P(Y>z)=1-\left(1-F_{X}(z)\right)\left(1-F_{Y}(z)\right)$$

using the CDF's of $X$ and $Y$ we get:
$$F_{z}(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & z \leq 0 \\
1-e^{-\left(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}\right) z} & z>0
\end{array}\right\}$$

So the PDF of $Z$ is:
$$f_{Z}(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\left(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}\right) e^{-\left(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}\right) z} & z>0 \\
0 & \text { else }
\end{array}\right\}$$

Now can i get any hint to find conditional distribution of $Z$ given $Z=X$?

Comment: THe conditional distribution of $Z$ given $Z=X$ is just equal to the distribution of $X$. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

> Now can i get any hint to find conditional distribution of Z given Z=X?

Just use Bayes' Rule. Note: that $\{Z=z, X=Z\}=\{X=z, X<Y\}$

$$f_Z(z\mid Z=X)~{=f_{X}(z\mid X<Y)\\~\vdots}$$